# Is there a Windows Docker containers eqivalent to tmpfs volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, windows-11, windows-container, ramdisk

On Linux I can mount RAM via `tmpfs` as a volume into my Linux containers if I need fast file access for temporary data.

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/

Linux example:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --tmpfs /ram-disk:size=1G ubuntu
```

Is there an eqivalent for Windows containers? (Not Linux containers on WSL2!)

- https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images

My specific use case looks like this: I have a computer with 128 GB RAM and Windows 11, running a GitLab runner that processes pipelines via Docker CI. Only one container with a RAM disk should run at a time, as this largely utilizes the system resources anyway. I would like to show this container 80 GB RAM as a file system, which is empty when the container is started and whose contents are discarded when the container is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The tmpfs is not available for Windows. You can use volumes or bind mounts, but these require actual disks.